# Issues with NSInvocation NSTimer and NSMethodSignature

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to get a button to create a NSTimer which in turn will call a function (refreshView) to refresh UI elements, but I am having problems and I am not sure where the problem lies. Is the method signature wrong? Or am I getting the NSRunLoop part wrong? Or is it just horribly off base? Any help is appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)reload:(id)sender{
NSInvocation *displayInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self     methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(refreshView)]];
[displayInvocation setTarget:self];
NSTimer *slideShowTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                                     invocation:displayInvocation
                                                          repeats:YES];
[slideShowTimer fire];
NSRunLoop * a = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[a addTimer:slideShowTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];}

-(void)refreshView{
[slideshow1 displayWithView:MajorImageView topicLabel:TopicLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems very complicated for nothing. Do you want to (1) start a timer to call [refreshView] periodically, or (2) call it later.

For (1), simply setup a timer with,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds 
                                 target:(id)target 
                               selector:(SEL)aSelector 
                               userInfo:(id)userInfo 
                                repeats:(BOOL)repeats]
```

No need to use a method invocation, a target/action will be enough

For (2), if you want to call it later,

```
[NSObject performSelector:(SEL)aSelector 
               withObject:(id)anArgument 
               afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay]
```

Comment: To be completely clear, it should be mentioned that the timer created with `scheduledTimer...` is _already_ added to the run loop. The timer also does not need to be sent `fire`.